# How to prevent multiple threads from picking up same task from queue

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I want to run multiple threads in parallel. Each thread picks up a task from a task queue and executes that task.

```
from threading import Thread
from Queue import Queue
import time

class link(object):
    
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.name = str(i)

def run_jobs_in_parallel(consumer_func, jobs, results, thread_count, 
                         async_run=False):
    def consume_from_queue(jobs, results):
        while not jobs.empty():
            job = jobs.get()
            try:
                results.append(consumer_func(job))
            except Exception as e:
                print str(e)
                results.append(False)
            finally:
                jobs.task_done()
    #start worker threads
    if jobs.qsize() < thread_count:
        thread_count = jobs.qsize() 
    for tc in range(1,thread_count+1):
        worker = Thread(
            target=consume_from_queue, 
            name="worker_{0}".format(str(tc)), 
            args=(jobs,results,))
        worker.start()
    if not async_run:
        jobs.join()

def create_link(link):
    print str(link.name)
    time.sleep(10)
    return True
    
def consumer_func(link):
    return create_link(link)
    # create_link takes a while to execute

jobs = Queue()
results = list()
for i in range(0,10):
    jobs.put(link(i))
                
run_jobs_in_parallel(consumer_func, jobs, results, 25, async_run=False)
```

Now what is happening is, let say we have 10 link objects in jobs queue, while the threads are running in parallel, multiple threads are executing same task. How can I prevent this from happening?
Note - the above sample code does not have the problem describe above, but i have exactly same code except create_link method does some complex stuff.

Comment: Please edit the code in your question so it is a [mre] - anyone should be able to paste it into a file and _without adding anything_ run it to see the problem you’re seeing. You’ll have to provide some _minimal_ sample data, so the code shows the problem you’re seeing. You’ll probably have to add something like printing at suitable points to show the problem happening, but that’s what a [mre] is about.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is a lock object ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#lock-objects),[tutorial+examples](https://www.bogotobogo.com/python/Multithread/python_multithreading_Synchronization_Lock_Objects_Acquire_Release.php)). If you create an instance of such an object you can 'lock' some parts of your code, ensuring that only one thread executes this part at a time.

I guess in your case you want to lock the line `job = jobs.get()`.

First you have to create the lock in a scope where all threads have access to it. (You don't want a lock for every thread but a single lock for all your threads. That means creating the lock within your thread just before acquiring it won't work)

```
import threading    
lock = threading.Lock()
```

then you can use it on your line like:

```
lock.acquire()
job = jobs.get()
lock.release()
```

or

```
with lock:
  job = jobs.get()
```

The first thread to reach `acquire()` will lock the lock. other threads that try to `acquire()` the lock will pause until the lock gets unlocked again by calling `release()`.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no need of lock when multithreading. Queues are thread safe. See - https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/queue.html#module-Queue

> The queue module implements multi-producer, multi-consumer queues. It
> is especially useful in threaded programming when information must be
> exchanged safely between multiple threads. The Queue class in this
> module implements all the required locking semantics.